# Laravel / Vue / Bootstrap Authentication with Email Verification scaffold for Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am familiar with the Laravel/Vue stack, and am looking to start a new project in Laravel 8.

But in the documentation, I see no mention of the Laravel / Vue / Bootstrap authentication / email verification scaffold, that existed in prior versions.

All I can find are scaffolds that now use some sort of "proprietary" reactive components (Livewire/Inertia), that offer a scaffold with a loot of nice features out of the box (2FA, profile management, teams), but would unfortunately require going through a whole new learning curve (tailwind, livewire/inertia).

So my question is, can I still find a Laravel / Vue / Bootstrap authentication scaffold, preferrably with all (or at least some of) the features that seem to have been added in the new scaffolds (https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/introduction.html), but without having to learn new technologies/stacks or was that simply abandoned by the Laravel team?

Comment: Take a look at laravel ui, they separated out the old auth into its own package https://github.com/laravel/ui

Comment: thanks, but this is just a rewrite of the old laravel/ui for 8.0, it has none of the fancy new scaffold functionalities

Comment: "_So my question is, can I still find a Laravel / Vue / Bootstrap authentication scaffold..._" Yes, that would be laravel/ui, like @JacobBrassington mentioned.

Comment: You can use some related packages that designed for laravel like [Laravel OTP Manager](https://github.com/HamidMp/otp-manager)